# showing the locations and finding the nearest spot in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display my spots `NSArray *chSpot = [parser parseArray:responseObject];`
which receives 3 objects , I want to show each location regarding to its lat and long [image]

and find the nearest spot according to my location...I am using this code:

```
         NSArray *chSpot = [parser parseArray:responseObject];
```

//         GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[locLat doubleValue]
//                                                                 longitude:[locLong doubleValue]
//                                                                      zoom:4];

```
     mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:nil];
     mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
     mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;


     for (int i=0; i<chSpot.count; i++)
     {

         ChargingSpots *spot = [chSpot objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString *locLat = spot.LocationLat;
         NSString *locLong = spot.LocationLong;


         // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
         GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
         marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([locLat doubleValue], [locLong doubleValue]);
         marker.title = @"Amman";
         marker.snippet = @"Jordan";

         mapView_.delegate=self;
         marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
         marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car"];
         marker.map = mapView_;

     }

     //[mapView_ setSelectedMarker:marker];

     self.view = mapView_;
```

//
//
//         CLLocation *locationA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[locLat doubleValue] longitude:[locLong doubleValue]];
//
//         CLLocation *locationB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[locLat doubleValue]  longitude:[locLong doubleValue]];
//
//         CLLocationDistance distance = [ locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];
//
//         NSLog (@"%f",distance);

```
     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
     self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

     [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: What does your current code? Does it work? If not, what's your issue?

Comment: I have handled the showing spots issue, but now i want to find the distance between my current location and the spot i got and find the nearest one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your locationManager's delegate's method `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` you can get your current location and it provides the method to calculate distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location

`CLLocationDistance distA = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation: locationA];`
`CLLocationDistance distB = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation: locationB]; //etc`

Comment: from where can i get "currentLocation" value ?